# Create Linegrid in Vulkan (line in x and y direction is missing) [fixed]

Tags: c++, render, mesh, vulkan

i created a method to create a 3D line grid.
i orientated my code on the example of 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12.
When I run my vulkan based application, I get a line grid, but the last line in x and y direction are missing ([Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUIId.png)).
Can anyone help me fixing this problem.
My first thought are problems with the render Options Polygon Mode Line (`VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE`)
and Primitive Topology Line List (`VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_LIST`). But these functions are working finde after research.

The following code shows the creation of my grid:

```cpp
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 color;
};

Mesh Mesh::CreateGrid(DrawingInstance& instance, float width, float depth, unsigned int m, unsigned int n)
{
    // 3D Game Programming with DirectX 12 - P. 302ff

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    std::vector<uint32_t> indices;

    unsigned int vertexCount = m * n;
    unsigned int faceCount = (m - 1)*(n - 1) * 2;

    // Create vertices
    float halfWidth = width * 0.5f;
    float halfDepth = depth * 0.5f;

    float dx = width / (n - 1);
    float dz = depth / (m - 1);

    float du = 1.0f / (n - 1);
    float dv = 1.0f / (m - 1);

    vertices.resize(vertexCount);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        float z = halfDepth - i * dz;
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            float x = -halfWidth + j * dx;

            vertices[i*n + j].position = glm::vec3(x, z, 0.0f);
            vertices[i*n + j].color = glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        }
    }

    // create Indizes
    indices.resize(faceCount*3);

    unsigned int k = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j)
        {
            indices[k + 0] = i * n + j;
            indices[k + 1] = i * n + j + 1;
            indices[k + 2] = (i + 1)*n + j;

            indices[k + 3] = (i + 1)*n + j;
            indices[k + 4] = i * n + j + 1;
            indices[k + 5] = (i + 1)*n + j + 1;

            k += 6; // next quad
        }
    }
    return Mesh(instance, vertices, indices, VK_POLYGON_MODE_LINE , VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_LINE_LIST);
}
```

**Changes which solves the bug:**

```cpp
    
    // create Indizes
    
    indices.resize(faceCount * 4);

    unsigned int k = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < n - 1; ++j)
        {

            indices[k + 0] = i * n + j;
            indices[k + 1] = i * n + (j + 1);
            indices[k + 2] = i * n + (j + 1);
            indices[k + 3] = (i + 1) * n + j + 1;

            indices[k + 4] = (i + 1) * n + j + 1;
            indices[k + 5] = (i + 1) * n + j;
            indices[k + 6] = (i + 1) * n + j;
            indices[k + 7] = i * n + j;

            k += 8;
        }
    }
...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8UEq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, you have six indices per quad. Since it is a line list, that means three lines. Your second line is degenerate, so actually two lines. But quad is normally made of four lines. So unless the adjacent quad shares the extra lines, there will be nothing. And for the border quads, there are no adjacent quads. So the upper-left quad shows only the two lines.

Comment: oh, thank you. :)
Somehow I didn't think of that at all, but I implemented it know and it works.
Thank you for your help. :)

The changed code is above in my first post.